# How could I create a UIAlertView when there aren't any annotations generated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have the following to code to create all of my annotations based on data passed from my server, but sometimes there aren't any "deals" or pins that get generated, so how would I make it so when no deals are generated to create a UIAlertView? Here's the code I have to far:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]]) {

        MKPinAnnotationView *view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (view == nil) {
            view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                    initWithAnnotation:annotation
                    reuseIdentifier:identifier];

            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"No Deals! Please Try Your Request Again!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alert show];
        } else {

            view.annotation = annotation;
        }

       if([[(Annotation*)annotation phoneNumber] isEqualToString:@"0"]){


            view.enabled = YES;
            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
            // Create a UIButton object to add on the
            self.leftBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
            [self.leftBtn setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
            [view setLeftCalloutAccessoryView:self.leftBtn];

        }else{

            view.enabled = YES;
            view.canShowCallout = YES;

            // Create a UIButton object to add on the
            self.rightBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
            [self.rightBtn setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [view setRightCalloutAccessoryView:self.rightBtn];

        }

        if ([[(Annotation*)annotation phoneNumber] isEqualToString:@"1"]){

            view.enabled = YES;
            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
            // Create a UIButton object to add on the
            self.leftBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [self.leftBtn setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
            [view setLeftCalloutAccessoryView:self.leftBtn];

        }


        return view;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Is this something that I have to create in my http request method? Any ideas?

Comment: At some point you have to call either `addAnnotation` or `addAnnotations` based on the results you get back from the server. This is where you do it.